# Is there a way to launch dynamic web site of parse.com using Express on local machine?

Tags: parse-platform

I am developing a dynamic web site hosted on [parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#webapp) using Express. I have to deploy it when I want to check changes to my site design. Is there a way to launch this on my local machine?

If there is no way, can I check my site design quickly?

Comment: Assuming this is Node.js then yes you can. Depending on your platform there are guides to installing Node locally. A quick Google search will help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, this is Node.js, but I think this is not general Node.js environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:
https://github.com/mariusciocan/parse-cloud-debugger
this one works well for me.